# Task scheduler option for "Run whether the user is logged on or not" is disabled

Tags: windows-server, taskscheduler

This is how the task scheduler window is expected to look like:

[image]

In my case though, the option "Run whether user is logged on or not" is grayed out (disabled). This is a Windows Server 2012 machine and the accounts are subject to several group policies. I am trying to help the system administrator find and fix the cause. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here is what I did to resolve it.
Once the task was created I needed to go back into the task and change the settings.
Right Click the Task>Select Properties
Make the changes you want. You may be asked to provide a user name and account to run the task under. Hope this helps.